# Inflating Separate Menus for each Separate Item Click

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-contextmenu

From a lot of help here, I was able to use this code to inflate a context menu whenever an item is clicked. However, I cannot figure out how to inflate a individual, separate menus for each item. I want a different menu to pop up when a different item is clicked. Right now, no matter which item I click, the same menu pops up. How can I solve this?  Here is the code I am using.

```
package com.carouseldemo.main;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.carouseldemo.controls.Carousel;
import com.carouseldemo.controls.CarouselAdapter;
import com.carouseldemo.controls.CarouselAdapter.OnItemClickListener;
import com.carouseldemo.controls.CarouselAdapter.OnItemSelectedListener;
import com.carouseldemo.controls.CarouselItem;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {



     @Override
      public void onCreateContextMenu (ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.testmenu, menu);
      }

        /** Called when the activity is first created.
         * @return */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.radio);
    mp.start();
    Carousel carousel = (Carousel)findViewById(R.id.carousel);
    registerForContextMenu (carousel);
    carousel.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

                    public void onItemClick(CarouselAdapter<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {       

                            openContextMenu (view);
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                            String.format("%s has been clicked",
                                            ((CarouselItem)parent.getChildAt(position)).getName()),
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                            
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu,
                            View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

    });



    carousel.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){

                    public void onItemSelected(CarouselAdapter<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                    final TextView txt = (TextView)(findViewById(R.id.selected_item));

                            switch(position){
                            case 0:
                                    txt.setText("The cat (Felis catus), also known as the domestic cat or housecat to distinguish it from other felids and felines, is a small, usually furry, domesticated, carnivorous mammal that is valued by humans for its companionship and for its ability to hunt vermin and household pests. Cats have been associated with humans for at least 9,500 years, and are currently the most popular pet in the world. Owing to their close association with humans, cats are now found almost everywhere in the world.");
                                    break;
                            case 1:
                                    txt.setText("The hippopotamus (Hippopotamus amphibius), or hippo, from the ancient Greek for \"river horse\" (á¼±Ï€Ï€Î¿Ï€ÏŒÏ„Î±Î¼Î¿Ï‚), is a large, mostly herbivorous mammal in sub-Saharan Africa, and one of only two extant species in the family Hippopotamidae (the other is the Pygmy Hippopotamus.) After the elephant, the hippopotamus is the third largest land mammal and the heaviest extant artiodactyl.");
                                    break;
                            case 2:
                                    txt.setText("A monkey is a primate, either an Old World monkey or a New World monkey. There are about 260 known living species of monkey. Many are arboreal, although there are species that live primarily on the ground, such as baboons. Monkeys are generally considered to be intelligent. Unlike apes, monkeys usually have tails. Tailless monkeys may be called \"apes\", incorrectly according to modern usage; thus the tailless Barbary macaque is called the \"Barbary ape\".");
                                    break;
                            case 3:
                                    txt.setText("A mouse (plural: mice) is a small mammal belonging to the order of rodents. The best known mouse species is the common house mouse (Mus musculus). It is also a popular pet. In some places, certain kinds of field mice are also common. This rodent is eaten by large birds such as hawks and eagles. They are known to invade homes for food and occasionally shelter.");
                                    break;
                            case 4:
                                    txt.setText("The giant panda, or panda (Ailuropoda melanoleuca, literally meaning \"black and white cat-foot\") is a bear native to central-western and south western China.[4] It is easily recognized by its large, distinctive black patches around the eyes, over the ears, and across its round body. Though it belongs to the order Carnivora, the panda's diet is 99% bamboo.");
                                    break;
                            case 5:
                                    txt.setText("Rabbits (or, colloquially, bunnies) are small mammals in the family Leporidae of the order Lagomorpha, found in several parts of the world. There are eight different genera in the family classified as rabbits, including the European rabbit (Oryctolagus cuniculus), cottontail rabbits (genus Sylvilagus; 13 species), and the Amami rabbit (Pentalagus furnessi, an endangered species on Amami ÅŒshima, Japan)");
                                    break;
                            }

                    }

                    public void onNothingSelected(CarouselAdapter<?> parent) {
                    }

    }
    );

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simple in android. Only thing is you might have to add menu dynamically to the system instead of loading menu items using a xml file or load different xml menus based on the user's selection.

here is a sample application which shows how to do this,

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        if(flag)
        {
        menu.add("hi");
        menu.add("this");
        }
        else
        {
            menu.add("context");
            menu.add("menu");
        }
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
}
```

The above method based on a flag value inflates the different set of menu items.

Following is the onCreate() method which has a button and within that it registers for context menu every time it gets clicked.

```
    Button button=null;
    boolean flag=false;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(flag)
            {
                flag=false;
            }
            else
            {
                flag=true;
            }
            registerForContextMenu(v);
            openContextMenu(v);
        }
    });
    }
```

And here is the output,

When the flag is true,

[image]

And when the flag is false,

[image]

And I believe the key is to call the `registerForContextMenu(v);` when you need to load new menu items.

Comment: Okay, thank you. But what if I want to open a ListView instead of a second menu? So if the flag is true, it opens the menu. But if the flag is false, it opens a ListView instead. Or vice versa. If the flag is true, it opens the ListView and if the flag is false, it opens the menu. Whichever is easier.

Comment: then you have to check for the flag in the click event, and open context menu or open listview. But i am not sure what kind of listview you are expecting. this is with respect to your problem. So I believe you have to plan how to handle the condition. So you asked separate menu for each click and I have posted my idea of how you could inflate different menus based on conditions.

Comment: It was. But I have six items. Three of them bring up "hi" and "this". The other three bring up "context" and "menu". How do I make it so only two of the clicked items work to bring these menus up? And the other four do not bring the menus up.

Comment: This only works with two items. How can it work if you have six items? I need a separate menu for each.